# Setting a column with a Page value for every million rows

Tags: sql-server

```
   Users
    -RowID
    -PageNumber
    -...
```

For each 1 million ROWS, I want TO SET the value OF the PageNumber WITH an increment number.

So 1 to 1 000 000 will have a PageNumber of 1.  Then from 1 000 001 to 2 000 000 will have a PageNumber of 2 and so on...

Comment: Possible duplciate of [Group rows into sets of 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25436141/group-rows-into-sets-of-5)?

Comment: Do you have any column like auto increment or values can be ordered by values with a column?

Comment: @mkRabbani yes RowID is autoincrement.

Answer (score 1):

Just some math using a running row number.

```
SELECT 
  FLOOR((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) + 999999) / 1000000)
FROM 
  YourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of ntile function to get your expected output. First you need to set a static value of 1 million and then get the number of partitions required based on total count / total partitions.

```
Declare @valueset int = 1000000 
Declare @totalcount  bigint  = (Select count(1) total from yourtable) 
Declare @totalpartition int = (select ceiling(@totalcount*1.0/@valueset*1.0)) 

--select @totalpartition 

select ntile(@totalpartition) over (order by somecolumn  ) pagenumber,* from yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

As you confirmed RowId is a auto increment column, you can do this to update your new column-

**SELECT:**

```
SELECT *,
CASE 
    WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY RowId) %100000 = 0 
        THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY RowId) /100000 
    ELSE  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY RowId) /100000 + 1 
END 
FROM your_table
```

**UPDATE:**

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT RowId,
    CASE 
        WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY RowId) %100000 = 0 
            THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY RowId) /100000 
        ELSE  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY RowId) /100000 + 1 
    END NV
    FROM your_table
)

UPDATE A
SET A.NewColumnName = B.NV
FROM your_table A
INNER JOIN CTE B ON A.RowId= B.RowId
```

> Caution: Please try with test data first.